# Adding environment variable to compile transport code

Tags: cmake, ignition-fortress

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I'm writting some piece of code to extract info from gazebo simulations, making use of a topic that is being published in transport.

My issue is, using the publisher/subscriber CMakeList.txt example file, cmake is unable to find the library file to do its job. I have no clue on which directory CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH should point to, since the only transport11 file I've found is /usr/include/ignition/transport11.

My installation is ignition Fortress from binaries in Ubuntu 20.04, and I've checked with apt that libignition-transport11-dev is installed.

The error message is as follows:

```
Starting >>> ros_gz_pose_transport
--- stderr: ros_gz_pose_transport                         
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findgz-transport11.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "gz-transport11", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gz-transport11"
  with any of the following names:

   gz-transport11Config.cmake
   gz-transport11-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "gz-transport11" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "gz-transport11_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "gz-transport11" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.


make: * * * [Makefile:398: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
---
Failed   <<< ros_gz_pose_transport [2.06s, exited with code 2]
```

**My CMakeLists.txt is:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2 FATAL_ERROR)
project(ros_gz_pose_transport)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(ignition-cmake2 REQUIRED)



find_package(ignition-plugin1 REQUIRED COMPONENTS register)
set(IGN_PLUGIN_VER ${ignition-plugin1_VERSION_MAJOR})

# Find the Gazebo Transport library
find_package(gz-transport11 QUIET REQUIRED OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS log)
set(GZ_TRANSPORT_VER ${gz-transport11_VERSION_MAJOR})







find_package(ignition-gazebo6 REQUIRED)
add_library(SampleSystem SHARED src/SampleSystem.cc)
set_property(TARGET SampleSystem PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
target_link_libraries(SampleSystem
  PRIVATE ignition-plugin${IGN_PLUGIN_VER}::ignition-plugin${IGN_PLUGIN_VER}
  PRIVATE ignition-gazebo6::ignition-gazebo6
  gz-transport${GZ_TRANSPORT_VER}::core)


add_executable(pose_publisher_example src/pose_publisher_example.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(pose_publisher_example rclcpp geometry_msgs)
add_executable(publish_once src/publish_once.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(publish_once rclcpp geometry_msgs)
add_executable(hello src/hello_package.cpp)

target_include_directories(pose_publisher_example PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)
target_compile_features(pose_publisher_example PUBLIC c_std_99 cxx_std_17)  # Require C99 and C++17

install(TARGETS 
  pose_publisher_example
  hello
  publish_once
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()
```

Thanks in advance,
Diego

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28890/adding-environment-variable-to-compile-transport-code./) by [Diego Cubillo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/154081/diego-cubillo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The `ign->gz` migration may not be available in the version of libignition-transport11 you have. You need libignition-transport11 11.3.0 to use the `gz` prefix.

---

Originally posted by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) with karma: 704 on 2023-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Diego Cubillo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/154081/diego-cubillo/) on 2023-03-17**:
Hi azeey.
My  transport11 version is 11.4.0. Anyway, if I switch from gz- to ignition- and from GZ_ to IGN_ nothing changes. There should be a directory with the library info to give to cmake anyways, right?

**Comment by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) on 2023-03-21**:
Once you change the cmake library names to have `ignition-`, you probably have to clear cmake's cache. The easiest way is to remove the build directory and run cmake again. Have you tried that?

**Comment by [Diego Cubillo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/154081/diego-cubillo/) on 2023-03-24**:
I hadn't, and now it works. Thanks!!!